# Error in if (sjmisc::is_empty(x)) return(NULL) : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to run a simple frequency of a categorical variable which has `NA` values as well as textual ones, but I keep getting the same error mistake whatever I do.

```
frq(X201504_201812_Met$`Object of search`, out = "v")
```

> Error in if (sjmisc::is_empty(x)) return(NULL) :    missing value
>   where TRUE/FALSE needed

It's a massive dataset so I ran the dput() command only on the 'Object of search' variable. This is pretty much what I got, except that there was much more of this (there's over half a million lines of data):

> dput(X201504_201812_Met$`Object of search`)
>   c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   "Offensive weapons", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", 
>   "Fireworks", "Controlled drugs", "Stolen goods", "Controlled drugs", 
>   "Controlled drugs", "Offensive weapons", "Controlled drugs", 
>   "Fireworks", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", "Evidence of offences under the Act", 
>   "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", 
>   "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", 
>   "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", 
>   "Offensive weapons", "Stolen goods", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", 
>   "Offensive weapons", "Offensive weapons", "Controlled drugs", 
>   "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs"
>   )

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: May you provide us with a fully reproducible example by pasting `dput(X201504_201812_Met)` Best!

Comment: At least a`head`?

Comment: Hi Jonny! Thanks for the quick reply. I edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for editing it! Now I think I cracked the problem.
It seems that you variable is still `character`. You need to convert it into `factor` first:

```
frq(as.factor(X201504_201812_Met$`Object of search`), out = "v")
```

This should do the trick!

Comment: My pleasure! Please, next time add the library where your function comes from and a minimal sample of your data! We will [try to] help you faster!